# Methods in super that will be subclassed anyway (Cocoa)

Tags: cocoa, subclass, super

Sorry if this is a repost but I couldn't quite search for it because I can't explain it in a few words. I have a super class with lots of methods but they will always (not all of them) be subclassed. From the super I need to run those methods. I could either leave the methods in super empty or I could just not type them in super but call them anyway like so `[self myMethod]` and it will call my subclassed method even if it doesn't exist in super. This works but Xcode gives me an error though. `'superclass' may not respond to '-subclassmethod'`

What should I do so I won't get the warnings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer to define the unimplemented methods in the superclass like this:

```
@interface GLObject : NSObject {}
- (id)someSubclassProvidedMethod;
@end

@implementation GLObject
- (id)someSubclassProvidedMethod {
  [self doesNotRecognizeSelector: _cmd];
}
@end
```

It's almost entirely redundant, because the Objective-C runtime would eventually call `-doesNotRecognizeSelector:` if I didn't define the method at all. But because I do define it, it's in the class's interface which both keeps the compiler happy and provides me with some documentation.

Comment: Just don't forget to document the methods in the header as being abstract (intended to be overridden).

Comment: This sounds great but my methods are non-void and the compile will still nag about the return value.

Comment: @Michael then return some pointless value after calling `-doesNotRecognizeSelector:`, or mark the method as non-returning.

Comment: By 'marking it as non-returning', do you mean (void)myMethod instead of (NSString *)myMethod?

Comment: I do almost the same thing but instead of calling doesNotRecognizeSelector: I usually do something like NSAssert2( FALSE, @"'%@' is abstract and must be overridden for '%@'", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), self);

Comment: @Michael no, I mean `__attribute__ ((noreturn))`.

Comment: @Graham sorry to get back to you but, I added the noreturn attribute in the declaration of my method like this -(NSString *)myMethod __attribute__ ((noreturn)); and now I get another warning saying 'noreturn function does return' while everything there is in the method is just the doesNotRecognizeSelector call.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than the superclass, you could declare the methods in a [protocol](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProtocols.html), what is called a "interface" in other languages.

```
@protocol MyProtocol
-(id)myMethodWith:(id)arg;
@end
```

Change the type declaration of the variables to declare that the object conforms to the protocol.

```
-(id)doStuffWith:(SuperClass <MyProtocol> *)aThing and:(id)another {
    return [aThing myMethodWith:another]
}
```

Note that you won't be able to pass an instance of your SuperClass to `doStuffWith:and:`, since it won't implement MyProtocol, but it sounds like that's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was a little weird, but here it is:

```
@protocol JSDog <NSObject>
- (void)yipe;
@end

@interface JSDog : NSObject
@end

@implementation JSDog

+ (void)initialize {
  if ([self isSubclassOfClass:[JSDog class]] && ![self conformsToProtocol:@protocol(JSDog)]) {
    NSAssert(false, @"Subclasses of JSDog must conform to <JSDog>.");
  }
}

@end
```

Having a protocol with the same name as a class is precedented in `NSObject`. Because methods in a formal protocol a by default `@required`, you will be protected on both ends: in **compile-time**, if your `JSDog` subclass purports to conform to `<JSDog>`, but doesn't implement `-yipe`, you will receive an error; at **runtime**, if your subclass does not claim to conform with `<JSDog>`, you will receive a warning when the subclass is instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

I lately like using NSAssert for this task:

```
- (BOOL)proceedForVersion:(int)versionInteger
{
    NSAssert(false, @"This method needs to be overridden in a subclass of iMBApertureAbstractParser");

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Good idea. A `#define` for this would prove useful.